# Any reason in using Start Transaction/Commit statement in a MySQL script which contain multiple DDL statements such as Create table and Alter Table?

Tags: mysql

Is there any reason I should have a START TRANSACTION at the top of my SQL script (COMMIT on the bottom) if my script only contains multiple DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE..etc?

eg.

START TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE ......

CREATE TABLE2 ......

CREATE TABLE3 ....

COMMIT

Comment: All those DDL statement contain an implicit commit [See the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) Therefore each infact will do its own commit as each statement completes. So the Transaction is not required

Comment: So there is no reason to have START TRANSACTION and COMMIT statement?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Many thanks for your confirmation